# How to generate a network map?

Tags: mac, networking

We have a range of static IP address at our lab and I don't recall which IP address are being used. Is there a program for OS X that can scan a range of IP address and tell us if a computer/router/or printer is using it? Need to do this so we can figure out which IP address we can still assign (our lab manager is on vacation for a few weeks and we can't find out if there is a list somewhere of what addresses are assigned).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angry IP Scanner is probably the best tool for this on Windows and I have not personally tested it, but I have seen that it is also available for Macs.

[Download Link](http://www.angryip.org/w/Download)

Comment: I checked this out, it's very simple and does the trick. thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Probably the best network scanner out there:

http://nmap.org/

OS X installation:

http://nmap.org/book/inst-macosx.html

To ping a range of IP's:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.2.0/24
```

Comment: Fact: This is the tool Trinity used in The Matrix Reloded. http://nmap.org/movies.html ... and remember to set your terminal colors to green on black before running :-)

Comment: I actually tried nmap's gui earlier today and I didn't trust the results. The commands line works perfectly though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to be careful with this.  If youhave devices such as laptops or desktops which may be turned off then they won't respond to a ping or any type of other scan.  Your best bet is to run an IP scanner several times throughout the day and throughout the week and take the machines which respond and add them to the list of used IPs.